# Ruby Rails ActiveRecord Association, has_one through a belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Models

```
class GameResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game_result
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "game_results", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "result"
end

create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "game_result_id"
end
```

I can currently retrieve the result by calling

```
@game.game_result.result
```

By building the correct association, I believe I should be able to call

```
@game.result
```

I have tried many configurations of a has_many/one through associations to no avail, such as:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game_result
  has_one :result, through: :game_result, source: :result
end
```

I would appreciate any advice on how to go about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game_result  
end
```

You want to call

`@game.game_result.result` as `@game.result`

You can't do that with associations, you'd need to use rails' delegator

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game_result  
  delegate :result, to: :game_result, allow_nil: true
end
```

You might not need allow_nil on the end, depends on your circumstances.

Essentially this is just a shorthand way of having

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game_result  

  def result
    return nil if game_result.nil?
    game_result.result
  end
end
```

Comment: This solution worked great. And as yet, I did not need to implement the allow_nil.

Comment: Essentially you'll need allow_nil if you can have a situation where a game won't have a game result associated.  So if you can't have that situation then you'll never need it.